# Electromagnetic or microwave cooling

Tags: electromagnetism, microwave

Heat means stored kinetic energy in matter. Microwave owens and induction heaters works on increasing kinetic energy on matter. Is it possible to make inverse of this  heaters like cooler. We can decrese kinetic energy by using like electromagnetic slower device. It will change many things in engineering.

Comment: Peltier cooling seems closely related.

Comment: Im searching it in lower frequencies for reaching deeper atoms or molecules. isn't it a surface method with special materials

Comment: @acs Perhaps you should rephrase your question: do you mean in theory or in practice? In practice, what you're describing is **definitely** not possible yet. In theory, who knows? Perhaps you could better ask that at Physics SE, since that question is beyond engineering and into the domain of theoretical physics.

Comment: Im just searching existance of solution.  May be a name or a term will be begining. I will ask same thing in physics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that it is possible, and [it works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling). The bad news is that it only works on [very small structures](http://www.tgdaily.com/trendwatch-features/33867-radio-waves-used-to-super-cool-tiny-structures); it is possible to cool down a few molecules, but you won't be flash freezing turkeys any time soon.

Comment: It is based on laser. Im searching it in lower frequencies for reaching deeper atoms or molecules. Laser doesnt reach deep places because of low wavelength